# Neural network doesn't work without bias

Tags: javascript, vb.net, networking, backpropagation

I created a neural network with bias in Javascript and it works for the XOR problem, then when I recreated it in VB.Net without bias, it does not work. So, I removed bias from my Javascript neural net and that also causes it to not work.

The sort of results I get for XOR are:

### Inputs | Output

1  1  | 0.4

-1  1  | -0.4

1 -1  | 0.3

-1  1  | -0.3

(Using TanH activation function)

So as you can see, if the first input is a minus the output will be a minus, and they will be the same value depending on the second output (1 = 0.4 output, -1 = 0.3 output). When I add bias it works perfectly but not without.

Any help would be great,
Thanks.

Comment: What help do you need?.  You normally have a bias, why are you removing it?

Comment: You need a bias to set the threshold of activation for your nodes. Without a bias, you'll need to have some other mechanism to achieve that.

Comment: @Keith my neural network should learn xor without bias, but it only works with bias, one of my lecturers at school told me this meant my neural network doesn't work

Comment: @Carcigenicate what do you mean by threshold of activation?

Comment: @FinleyDabinett The exact meaning depends on the activation function you're using. If you don't have a bias, and are using a step activation function, if the node achieves an activation above 0 (or 0.5), the node will fire. If you want to change how much activation a node requires to fire (its threshold), you use a bias, or similar mechanism. A bias node is the most straightforward though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate what happens when a node fires? What does that mean it does? I did neural networks a while ago and have forgotten much about them

Comment: @FinleyDabinett It propogates its activation to the nodes connected to it. Or in other words, passes its "signal" along the network.

Comment: @Carcigenicate so should my neural network solve xor without bias or does it need bias?

Comment: @FinleyDabinett AFAIK, most nets should use them. The only downside is, using them adds to the number of variables that need to be optimized. If the problem doesn't require their use, it can slow down the learning. I can't remember if xor requires using them.

Comment: @Carcigenicate ok, thanks for your help!

Comment: You can get xor without bias, but not using Tanh.  It should work using a linear activation.  Tanh won't work because each node is going to max out -1, +1.  Think about that for a while :)  basically the hidden layer won't have much to work with..